# Giving HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request | Zoho API | searchParams |

Tags: api, zoho

I am referring this documentation from Zoho
https://www.zoho.com/people/api/forms-api/search-record.html

I am unable to get desired results

I even tried with example mentioned on website too using URL

```
https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms/employee/getRecords?searchParams={searchField: Employeestatus, searchOperator: Is, searchText : Active}
```

and passing auth token

But it returns

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
```

[image: Error while fetching using postman]

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does say GET here (at least at the time of writing) - but the request does actually work with a POST and sending the `searchParams` as form data.

curl example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms/employee/getRecords' \
--header 'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken [...]' \
--form 'searchParams="{searchField: Employeestatus, searchOperator: Is, searchText: Active}"'
```

Also, make sure to use the right dedicated domain for your Zoho CRM v2 API for all requests!