# Cannot use searchParams on Zoho People API (HTTP Status 400)

Tags: rest, get, postman, zoho, bad-request

*(related to [Giving HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request | Zoho API | searchParams |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433210/giving-http-status-400-bad-request-zoho-api-searchparams?newreg=079396691a41478b927a1495ce0f9ed5) - following the official documentation at https://www.zoho.com/people/api/forms-api/search-record.html)*

When sending a GET request via Postman to fetch leave-records for today by using the following (exported as curl)

```
curl --location -g \
  --request GET "https://people.zoho.eu/people/api/forms/leave/getRecords?searchParams={searchField:'To',searchOperator:'After',searchText:'02-Mar-2022'}|{searchField:'From', searchOperator: 'Before', searchText : '02-Mar-2022'}" \
  --header "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.abcd1234.abcd1234"
```

as provided by the documentation, I receive only a `HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request` error response.

---

However, sending the same request without the `searchParams`, getting all leave records as a response, does work. So the URL region and the Auth to the API are correct in my case.

I authenticated as documented and received the token, using my *clientId* and *clientSecret* using the *ZOHOPEOPLE.forms.ALL* scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(similar answer as for [Giving HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request | Zoho API | searchParams |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433210/giving-http-status-400-bad-request-zoho-api-searchparams))*

---

The documentation does say GET here (at least at the time of writing) - but the request does actually work with a POST and sending the `searchParams` as form-data.

curl example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://people.zoho.eu/people/api/forms/leave/getRecords' \
--header 'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken [...]' \
--form 'searchParams="{searchField: To, searchOperator: After, searchText: 10-Mar-2022}|{searchField: From, searchOperator: Before, searchText: 10-Mar-2022}"'
```

Also note that I could actually omit the quotes in the `searchParams` for better legibility with less escaping.